# char * ( 64 bit ( windows 7 ) )

Tags: c++

Suppose, that i have the code:

```
// My.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) 
{
   if ( argc > 1 )
      std::cout << argv[ 1 ] << std::endl;
}
```

( i use MVSC++ 2008 )

when i run my program in cmd.exe:

```
My.exe argument
```

i get this output :

```
a r g u m e n t
```

why?????

Comment: looks like you cut out the relevant code -- your example won't even compile

Comment: Some of your code appears to be missing

Comment: Try redirecting the output to a file (`my.exe argument >output.dat`) and then open `output.dat` in a hex editor to see what bytes are *really* output. This will be helpful in discovering what's going wrong.

Comment: Your example works for me as expected. Check and make sure your code you posted is actually the code you're using.

Answer (score 5):

Might be a character code problem. Try replacing "std::endl" with "\n" and see. Also, are you compiling as Unicode?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're compiling with the Unicode character set option. Go to the project properties and under the *General* page change to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set". Alternately, if you want to use UTF-16 change the `main()` function to:

```
int wmain( int argc, wchar_t **argv )
```

Also, use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout` to print the arguments.